# I can't get my Macbook Pro to print to an IP addressable printer

Tags: macos, macbook, network-printer

Running Macbook Pro OS X 10.6.3
Accessing an HP OfficeJet 5610 plugged in the USB port of a US Robotics router.

I tried several combinations of:

Protocol:

- Internet Printing Protocol (IPP)
- Line Printer Daemon (LPD)
- HP JetDirect (socket)

Address:

- http://192.168.1.10:1631/printers/HP5610
- 192.168.1.10:1631/printers/HP5610
- http://192.168.1.10:1631
- 192.168.1.10:1631
- 192.168.1.10
- ...

Driver:

- HP OfficeJet 5600 Series

Whenever I try to print, it fails while saying "connected to printer" or "Printer is busy...zill try again in X seconds"

Both Windows 7 and Windows XP computers on the network can successfully access this printer, identifying it as "HP5610 on http://192.168.1.10:1631/"

I tried clearing all tasks and printers (ctrl-click in the menu), and resetting it to (socket, http://192.168.1.10:1631/printers/HP5610, HP5600 series) but to no success.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your printer is on and connected to the USB port on the router.
2. In OS X go to System Preferences.
3. Click on Print & Fax.
4. Click the lock (to unlock) to make changes. Enter your password if you need to.
5. Click on the plus (+) sign at the left to add a printer.
6. In Leopard/Snow Leopard click on the IP tab.
7. In the Protocol drop down, select HP JetDirect - Socket.
8. In the Address drop down, type the IP Address of your printer (192.168.1.10)
9. Leave Queue blank.
10. Give a descriptive name [Network Printer].
11. Give a descriptive location.
12. In the Print Using drop down either select your driver or choose the "select a driver to use" option.
13. Choose the appropriate driver for your printer.
14. Press OK and then click Add.

That should do it. Always add a new printer instead of modifying an existing configuration. Click the lock to apply and save your changes.

Source: http://aquatsr.com/static/ddwrt_wl520gu.pdf (Configuring a Printer in Mac OS X)